# Angular Application Will Not Handle MongoDB Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I have been beating my head against a wall for this one. I literally cannot figure this out.

I have a REST API that will show the data in a browser. I can use an HTTP tester and put and pull from this API just fine.

My angular app can populate itself via ANY OTHER json URL (https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.json for example) except mine, so I am betting its an issue with my configuration here.

Below I have pasted the code I am using to run the node server as well as the angular http request. I understand if you cannot answer but if you can send me to the right place that would be awesomesauce.

server.js:

```
// Dependencies

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

// Connect to Mongoose (MongoDB)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test')


// Build Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Router

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));


// Start Server

app.listen(9000)
console.log('Yo, shits on port 9000')
```

api.js:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

// Models
var Card = require('../models/cards')

// Routes
Card.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Card.register(router, '/cards')

// Return Router

module.exports = router;
```

cards.js (schema document):

```
// Dependencies
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// Schema
var cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    desc: String,
    cardtype: String
});


// Return model
module.exports = restful.model('Cards', cardSchema);
```

Here are my angular portions -

app.js:

```
var storyApp = angular.module('storyApp', ['ngRoute']);

storyApp.controller('cardController', function ($scope, $http) {



    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://data.stonegiants.org/api/cards"
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.listData = response.data;
    });

});

storyApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/cards.html',
            controller: 'cardController'
        })
        .when('/upload', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/upload.html',
            controller: 'cardController'
        });
});
```

The partial in questions, cards.html:

```
<div class="content" data-ng-model="cardController">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in listData | filter:seachText">
        <div class="card-title">
            <p>{{ card.title }}</p>
            <img ng-src="{{ card.image }}" />
            <p>{{ card.author }}</p>
            <p>{{ card.desc }}</p>
            <p>{{ card.cardtype }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have left my API up for you to see that it does work via a web browser (http://data.stonegiants.org/api/cards). If you input any other json URL, say the one I posted above, it works just fine.

Advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Firefox console gives me this response:     `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://data.stonegiants.org/api/cards. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`    Try adding    `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`    to the response headers.?

Comment: So laney had the correct answer here to get it to send me the data - the console now sees it after I have added this:
```app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
});
```
Now my error is with the app not displaying from the JSON it receives, which is a new issue. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped. I added it as an answer.

Comment: Your new issue might be that you have    `data-ng-model="cardController"`   in your cards.html, this should be    `data-ng-controller="cardController"`    or remove it altogether if you have defined the controller in the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox console gives me this response:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://data.stonegiants.org/api/cards. (Reason:
>   CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Try adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the response headers.?

Comment: This was correct. I finally got it all working after changing my call to the following:

```$http.get('http://data.stonegiants.org/api/cards').success(function(response) {
        $scope.listData = response;
    });
```
 I added this to my server.js per the suggestion:


```app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  next();
});```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit with your code. If you're getting a response in your browser (and I don't see anything wrong with the code) I'm guessing it's an issue with your angular...

Since I can't access your data using $http (Cross-Domain), I just copy and pasted it in. As-is the code still didn't produce the expected output. If you weren't using a partial, you would need to set the data-ng-app attribute and change data-ng-model to data-ng-controller, such that the line

```
<div class="content" data-ng-model="cardController">
```

would become

```
<div data-ng-app="storyApp" class="content" data-ng-controller="cardController">
```

I don't have any experience with angular-route.js, but since you are using a partial, if those attritbutes are set elsewhere, try simply removing the data-ng-model attribute from your div and see if that works ! I would also suggest running your partial in isolation to make sure you are getting a response from the server... so run something like this in a browser

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script>
var storyApp = angular.module('storyApp', []);

storyApp.controller('cardController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = "test!"
    $scope.listData = [];
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : 'http://data.stonegiants.org/api/cards'
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.listData = response
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="storyApp" class="content" data-ng-controller="cardController">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in listData | filter:seachText">
        <div class="card-title">
            <p>{{ card.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ card.author }}</p>
            <p>{{ card.desc }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck!